# let visitors share blog posts on their facebook

Tags: wordpress

There are a lot of different facebook plugins to be found. I have tried a lot but have not found one that does what I need.
I want a facebook "share" button to be placed on all posts on my site. When visitors press the button I want a post to their facebook page containing the featured image and lets say the first 100 characters of the text. Is this possible? Does anyone know of a plugin that does this?

All plugins that I tried only put a link to to the blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best plugin can be found here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-share-new/ 
It will let people share the post and shows to you how many times your post was shared.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I feel real stupid but can't get this to work. When using "Facebook share button" I am able to share on my facebook but not with featured image etc. When using the recommended Open Graph API version instead I will not be able to post to facebook anymore.

Comment: Haha ok so found out why not working. My site was not live so I think facebook could not find my page and that is why it was not shown on facebook.